# Can't get a random element out of ListArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, debugging, random

Trying to get a random string out of ListArray on the button pressed. Always getting the same, second element. No matter how big the array is.

Here's what I have on key pressed:

```
int randIndex = getRandomIndex(ListArray.size());
String chosenItem = ListArray.get(randIndex);
```

Method `getRandomIndex` is claimed beforehand and looks like this:

```
public int getRandomIndex(int size) {
        return (1+(int)Math.random()*size);
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast from `int` to `double` has precedence over the multiplication by `size`. When you cast `Math.random()` to an `int`, the decimal is dropped and the result is `0`. Thus, `getRandomIndex` will always return `1`.

In other words,

```
return (1 + (int) [some double variable] * size);
```

is the same as

```
return 1 + (0)*size;
```

which is the same as

```
return 1;
```

---

Fix it with:

```
private static final Random rand = new Random();

public int getRandomIndex(int size) {
    return rand.nextInt(size);
}
```

This is more readable and ensures an even distribution of random numbers.

Comment: Use the `Random` class instead... it is more readable that way, to be honest.

Comment: I've been fighting with the `Random` for some time before I encountered people suggesting this way.

Comment: There's not much to fight... all you need to do is call `nextInt(size)`. Plus, `Math.random()` is implemented using the `Random` class (see the [**source code**](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Math.java.html)). The only difference is that it uses `nextDouble`, which doesn't really apply to your situation. So using `nextInt` on your own `Random` object better suits your purpose, decreases the chances that you mess up, and makes it easy for others to understand what your code is doing. I would certainly prefer `rand.nextInt(size)` over a somewhat complicated arithmetic calculation.

Comment: Problem is I'm not really familiar with Java and developing for Android is for me the way to learn it. Thank you for your tips.